# There is not field about company name in itunesconnect for first ios application

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an individual apple developer account. I tried to upload a new ios application, but I had a problem. There is an error message "Please enter a company name to use within the iTunes Store.", but there is no field for company name. This app will be the first app of this individual account. There is a screenshot here :

[image]

Thanks for helping...

Comment: I've the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a little trick.
In that screen once you have the error, you have to put the html inspector and look for "company" the field has a "ng-hide" class. Delete it ("ng-hide") in the html view an then you can see the company name field, fill it and it works ;)
[image]

[image]